# Limiting users/groups to certain ports through SSH, and chroot jail if necessary

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, chroot-jail

I have a private linux box (Ubuntu 10.04) which is running various applications, many of which I access remotely using local forwarding. Now I would like to provide access to a third party, however I don't want to give him any more than LocalForward access to specific ports.

He doesn't need any shell or scp/sftp access, so I'd prefer to restrict him from those entirely if possible. If he needs a shell for localforward, then I'm happy to concede that, but if so I'd prefer to jail him in his home area. I'm happy with the jailing part if need be, plenty of guides online as far as I can tell, unless there is something special relating to my case I should be aware of.

Thanks!